# How do I include a path to libraries in g++

Tags: path, compilation, g++

I am trying to include the path to extra libraries in my makefile, but I can't figure out how to get the compiler to use that path.  So far I have:

```
g++ -g -Wall testing.cpp fileparameters.cpp main.cpp -o test
```

and I want to include the path to

```
/data[...]/lib
```

because `testing.cpp` includes files from that library.  Also, I'm on a Linux machine.

EDIT: Not a path to a library.  Just to header files from that library that were included.  My bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make g++ search for header files in a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654013/how-to-make-g-search-for-header-files-in-a-specific-directory)

Answer (score 251, accepted):

To specify a directory to search for (binary) libraries, you just use `-L`:

```
-L/data[...]/lib
```

To specify the actual library name, you use `-l`:

```
-lfoo  # (links libfoo.a or libfoo.so)
```

To specify a directory to search for *include* files (different from libraries!) you use `-I`:

```
-I/data[...]/lib
```

So I think what you want is something like

```
g++ -g -Wall -I/data[...]/lib testing.cpp fileparameters.cpp main.cpp -o test
```

These compiler flags (amongst others) can also be found at the GNU GCC Command Options manual:

- [3.16 Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

Comment: Basically someplace before it's needed; the `-I` should come before the .cpp filenames, for example.

Comment: Is it possible to make the compiler figuure that out, like add the library to a system variable?

Comment: @Fred, yes, g++ understands [a whole bunch of environment variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) which can be used to control the include path, library path, etc.

Comment: what's the difference between -L and -I (capital i, not lower L)?

Comment: @Youda008 did you read this answer? It explains exactly that.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill i don't understand it. "To specify a directory to search" and "To specify a directory to search for include files". So what does it search in the first case?

Comment: @Youda008 Capital ell: search path for libraries. Capital eye: search path for include files. Small ell: name of library to link.

Comment: how can I do this for makefiles?

Comment: @ZuzooVn do what? The -L and -l flags would just go in the LDFLAGS variable.

Comment: Will include files really be placed in a lib directory?

Comment: @Viesturs Is this something that people do sometimes? Yes, absolutely.

Comment: The `-l:` is very important in `cygwin` because the library name is no longer following the traditional `Unix` naming convention for example `/usr/lib/libPocoFoundation.dll.a`.              So it becomes, `-l:libPocoFoundation.dll.a`. Know, that it is by Unix long tradition that `-lm` means link to `libm.so` and `cygwin` is part Unix and part Windows.

Answer (score 7):

In your MakeFile or CMakeLists.txt you can set CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS as below:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/path/to/your/folder")
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could setup environment variables.
Suppose you are using `bash`, then in `~/.bashrc`, write

```sh
C_INCLUDE_PATH="/data/.../lib/:$C_INCLUDE_PATH" ## for C compiler
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/data/.../lib/:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH" ## for Cpp compiler
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

and source it with `source ~/.bashrc`.
You should be good to go.