# How to make g++ search for header files in a specific directory?

Tags: directory, g++, header-files, include-path

I have a project (a library) that is subdivided into a few directories with code in them. I'd like to to have g++ search for header files in the project's root directory, so I can avoid different include paths for same header files across multiple source files.

Mainly, the `root/` directory has sub-directories `A/`, `B/` and `C/`, all of which have `.hpp` and `.cpp` files inside. If some source file in A wanted to include `file.hpp`, which was in B, it would have to do it like this: `#include "../B/file.hpp"`. Same for another source file that was in C. But, if A itself had sub-directories with files that needed `file.hpp`, then, it would be inconsistent and would cause errors if I decided to move files (because the include path would be `"../../B/file.hpp"`).

Also, this would need to work from other projects as well, which reside outside of `root/`. I already know that there is an option to manually copy all my header files into a default-search directory, but I'd like to do this the way I described.

**Edit:** all programs using the library must compile only with `g++ prog.cpp lib.a -o prog`. That means *permanently* setting the include path for g++!

Comment: Note the discussion in [What are the benefits of a relative path such as `#include "../include/header.h"` for a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597318/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-relative-path-such-as-include-header-h-for-a-hea)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A/code.cpp

```
#include <B/file.hpp>
```

A/a/code2.cpp

```
#include <B/file.hpp>
```

Compile using:

```
g++ -I /your/source/root /your/source/root/A/code.cpp
g++ -I /your/source/root /your/source/root/A/a/code2.cpp
```

Edit:

You can use environment variables to change the path g++ looks for header files. From man page:

> Some additional environments variables affect the behavior of the
>   preprocessor.
>
> ```
>    CPATH
>    C_INCLUDE_PATH
>    CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
>    OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
> ```
>
> Each variable's value is a list of directories separated by a special character, much like PATH, in which to look for header
>   files. The special character, "PATH_SEPARATOR", is target-dependent and determined at GCC build time.  For Microsoft Windows-based targets it
>   is a semicolon, and for almost all other targets it is a colon.
>
> CPATH specifies a list of directories to be searched as if specified with -I, but after any paths given with -I options on the
>   command line.  This
>              environment variable is used regardless of which language is being preprocessed.
>
> The remaining environment variables apply only when preprocessing the particular language indicated.  Each specifies a
>   list of directories to be
>              searched as if specified with -isystem, but after any paths given with -isystem options on the command line.
>
> In all these variables, an empty element instructs the compiler to search its current working directory.  Empty elements can
>   appear at the beginning
>              or end of a path.  For instance, if the value of CPATH is ":/special/include", that has the same effect as -I.
>   -I/special/include.

There are many ways you can change an environment variable. On bash prompt you can do this:

```
$ export CPATH=/your/source/root
$ g++ /your/source/root/A/code.cpp
$ g++ /your/source/root/A/a/code2.cpp
```

You can of course add this in your Makefile etc.

Comment: Hey, I've stated the question without one important detail, please see the edit, thanks!

Comment: @Bane, that changes everything :-). I edited my answer to include more options that can be used.

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for. How exactly can I edit those? (With a CLI instruction, that is, which I need to add to my library's makefile's install rule.)

Comment: @Bane, updated with instruction. Exact way of setting environment variable will depend on your environment. But you mentioned you are using `Makefile`. In that case, why can't you add `-I /path` flag in your `Makefile`? Why do you want compiler to be executed without any options?

Comment: Because some other projects might need the library, and I only want to move the `lib.a` file, not the header files. I could include `-I /path` into *their* makefiles, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 37):

```
gcc -I/path -L/path
```

- `-I /path` path to include,  gcc will find .h files in this path
- `-L /path` contains library files, `.a`, `.s`o

Answer (score 1):

it's simple, use the "-B" option to add .h files' dir to search path.

E.g. g++ -B /header_file.h your.cpp -o bin/your_command

Answer (score 0):

Headers included with #include <> will be searched in all default directories , but you can also add your own location in the search path with -I command line arg.

I saw your edit you could install your headers in default locations usually

```
 /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```

Confirm with compiler docs though.

Comment: Ya see above install includes in default locations for a quick resolution.