# Library file placement in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use the dynamic bitset provided by boost libraries. Downloaded the file  boost_1_55_0.tar.bz2 and extracted it into a folder named boost. In this folder I have put my source code file with the #include directive `#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>`, when I compile the source code, the compiler returns "No such file or directory". Where to place the source code?

Comment: Well if your source is also in the boost directory (which is not a good idea), then your include should be #include "dynamic_bitset.hpp",

Comment: What is the good idea then?

Comment: Put your code in a separate folder, then add the boost directory to your compiler's INCLUDE path (compiler-dependant)

Comment: Well, I am using g++ on Ubuntu. May you show me how to add the boost directory to the compiler's INCLUDE path?

Comment: If you bother to search SO, there are many entries, and on google also.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654013/how-to-make-g-search-for-header-files-in-a-specific-directory

Comment: Thank you! But why do capitalize "SO"?

Comment: Another resource is [the boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#examples) that shows examples for `dynamic_bitset`.  The best way to get help here is to clearly show what you've tried, what you expected and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile the program by putting the source code file in the the same directory that boost is in, and compiling using the command formula:

```
g++ -I /your/source/root /your/source/root/A/code.cpp
```

As mentioned in the [How to make g++ search for header files in a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654013/how-to-make-g-search-for-header-files-in-a-specific-directory)

Comment: This is bad. If you are on a UNIX like system, use your package manager to install Boost. After that you can just put your source whereever you want and compile it without adding any flags.

Comment: @pmr Does Boost exist on the Ubuntu Software Center?