# How to install nan.h on cygwin for g++?

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

I can't build this simple program on cygwin:

```
#include <nan.h>
int main(){}
```

I get this error message:

```
$ g++ a.cpp
a.cpp:1:17: fatal error: nan.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Is it possible to install something on cygwin to get correct nan.h?

Comment: What is `nan.h` and where did you get it from?

Comment: @Ron, this doesn't help, same message.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko In that case you need to supply the path to your header file.

Comment: nan.h is part of doubledouble package

Comment: if you;re using gyp you need to require(v8). If you;re using cmake you'll want to require() one of the many helper modules (google cmake v8)

Comment: @StepanYakovenko Did you follow their [installation instructions](https://boutell.com/fracster-src/doubledouble/doubledouble.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nan.h is an obsolete include of old gcc. On Cygwin NAN is defined on `math.h`

You can not use a software written in 2008
https://boutell.com/fracster-src/doubledouble/doubledouble.html
for such specific issue and just hope than it works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out where nan.h is located and than Add this path to the includes.

[How to make g++ search for header files in a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654013/how-to-make-g-search-for-header-files-in-a-specific-directory)

Comment: nan.h is missing in my /cygwin folder. Most probably it is deprecated and doubledouble is too old for modern C++ compiler to be built out of the box.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko I believe the `long double` intrinsic type should already serve you well.

Comment: Yes, but my final goal is to port doubledobule to Rust in order to emulate f128, which was deprecated recently.