# unable to compiling c++ with openCV even using 'pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` in Linux

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

good morning,
please I need help-
I have a file: s.cpp
that uses:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
```

and I wrote a makefile like this:

```
s: s.o
g++ s.o -o s


s.o: s.cpp
    g++ s.cpp -c `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

clean: rm -f s
```

and got the error:

```
 g++ s.cpp -c `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
s.cpp:9:10: fatal error: opencv2/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

please, I dont know what to do
please someone can help?

Comment: Compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g s.cpp -c $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)` in your `Makefile`. Add `-H` flag to understand what files are included. On [Debian](https://debian.org/) you need development packages related to OpenCV like `libopencv-dev`

Comment: I tried what you  @BasileStarynkevitch suggested:
`code` shape: shape.o
 g++ shape.o -o shape

shape.o: shape.cpp
 g++ -Wall -Wextra -g shape.cpp -c $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)  and it didnt change anything

Comment: Don't comment your own question. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66299998/edit) it to improve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912640/main-cpp110-fatal-error-opencv2-highgui-hpp-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

if you are are trying to link more libraries all together in one time using the pkg-config command, I solved my problems on code::blocks with the command

`pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4`

written in the *project->build option->"program name"->linker settings->other linker* option