# c++: g++ not seeing library on cmd

Tags: c++, cmd, compilation, g++, include

i'm trying to compile my code on cmd using g++ and i'm also using an include file which is located in:

"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Lib"

which is added to the project in:

"C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Lib"

and i want to compile it with:

g++ main.cpp

but i get the following error:

```
main.cpp:7:10: fatal error: FastIO.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <FastIO.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

which is a line of code in main.cpp, however when i run using visual studio it works just fine. I also tried running "g++ -I" with both directories and both gives the error "fatal error: no input files"

gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-2)
windows 10
visual studio 2019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make g++ search for header files in a specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654013)

Comment: Do you know how to use the `-I` option to `g++`, and know how it works?

Comment: yes, i tried that too but it gives "no input file" error, also red the documents...