# How to use g++ without Makefile to build cpp that makes calls to other header files?

Tags: g++, header-files

I am trying to build at the command prompt the following:

```
g++ -c ../../TRUNK/StringUtl.cpp -o StringUtl.o      // ok
g++ -c ../../TRUNK/CircularBuf.cpp -o CircularBuf.o  // ok
g++ -c ../../TRUNK/UartComm.cpp -o UartComm.o        // fatal error: CircularBuf.h: No such file or directory    THE header to his cpp file has #include "CircularBuf.h"
```

---

UartComm.h:  contents at the top of file

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// General inclusions
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CircularBufClass.h"
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654013/how-to-make-g-search-for-header-files-in-a-specific-directory) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This error is beacuse g++ is not able to find the header files.
 You would need to provide path of your header files using `-I<Path>` option.
Eg:

```
g++ -Iyourheaderfilepath/ -c ../../TRUNK/UartComm.cpp -o UartComm.o
```