How to include opencv headers without using cmake?
I installed the opencv library by using apt:
sudo apt install libopencv-dev libopencv-contrib-dev

But how to involve the installed library into my own project without using cmake? I tried directly including the headers but failed:
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main(){
    cv::Mat mat;

    return 0;
}

Errors:
algos/math/tt_opencv.cpp:2:9: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                        compilation terminated.

By the way, I compile the project by g++:
g++ tt_opencv.cpp -o test

Should i add an -I{path} option when compiling?

@drescherjm Then why the compilation failed?

After searching ubuntu I believe that file is supposed to be here: /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp looking at the filelist here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/arm64/libopencv-core-dev/filelist /usr/include should be in the system headers but not /usr/include/opencv4

Yes you need to add an appropriate -I option, and also -l and -L options.

This question is similar to: How to include header files in GCC search path?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654013/how-to-make-g-search-for-header-files-in-a-specific-directory

Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g ; there are tons of questions with answers on that topic.

You should add -I and -L option. Make notice, that -I shouldn't contain opencv2 folder (cause it's added inside #include). Sometimes, in very rare cases, some headers might be inside $libdir.
