# C++ JSON Compiling Issue

Tags: c++, xml, linux, json, installation

I installed the json spirit library on my linux mint machine using sudo apt-get install libjson-spirit-dev. However when I compile my code, I get this error saying:

> /usr/include/json_spirit_writer.h:14:40: fatal error: json_spirit_writer_options.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

This traces back to this line of code in my program: `#include <json_spirit.h>`

I am assuming there is some issue with the library I installed? I uninstalled and then reinstalled the library but that did not seem to work. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing you need to add an include path so that it can find #include jason_spirit_writer_options.h

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add /usr/include/ to your include path. If you're using g++ you would do this using the '-I' flag.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in Ubuntu-based version the libjson-spirit-dev package (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/json-spirit/+bug/1201764)

Since you're using Linux Mint, I'm guessing that's your issue.