# NTL header file not found

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ntl

I have downloaded and installed the NTL library on my Ubuntu. I'm currently using gedit to write my program and having included this `ZZ.h` header in my program. This is how i compile my program in the terminal: `- g++ keygen.cpp -o keygen -I ../include -L ../lib -lntl -lm`.

I'm pretty sure this line is correct but for some unknown reason, i get the following error:

```
KeyGen.cpp:9:20: error: NTL/ZZ.h: No such file or directory
KeyGen.cpp:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘int’
```

The solution seems pretty straightforward to me: which is to add the NTL library directly to my program folder. I did just that, but still i get the same error.

Comment: Do you actually have NTL/ZZ.h header in paths you g++ uses for headers. Try to run `cpp -I ../include -x c++ -v` to get the whole list of include directories

Comment: @user3159253 so meaning to say i MUST see NTL/ZZ.h in the include directories?

Comment: Surely you do. In one of include directories there should be a subdirectory called NTL and readable ZZ.h in it.

Comment: How did you install NTL library? From the package or from sources? I've checked ZZ.h does exist in <ntl-6.0.0>/include/NTL/

Comment: @user3159253 I installed the library following the instructions on the NTL website. Icreated a folder called 'include' within the `.cpp` folder and included the NTL library in that folder already. Since i don't see it.. What should i do?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the latest (6.0.0) version of NTL you may do as follows in your Ubuntu:

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-get install libntl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libntl-5.4.2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libntl-5.4.2 libntl-dev
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 112 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,035 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,016 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main libntl-5.4.2 amd64 5.4.2-4 [767 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main libntl-dev amd64 5.4.2-4 [1,268 kB]
Fetched 2,035 kB in 2s (1,017 kB/s)   
Selecting previously deselected package libntl-5.4.2.
(Reading database ... 59184 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libntl-5.4.2 (from .../libntl-5.4.2_5.4.2-4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libntl-dev.
Unpacking libntl-dev (from .../libntl-dev_5.4.2-4_amd64.deb) ...
Can not write log, openpty() failed (/dev/pts not mounted?)
Setting up libntl-5.4.2 (5.4.2-4) ...
Setting up libntl-dev (5.4.2-4) ..
user@host:~$
```

after that the complete compiled NTL library with all development headers is installed in your system and you may compile your program with it without any additional -I<path>.

If you need a newer version that your distro has (check http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/source/trusty/ntl) you may try to build the library package yourself.

Comment: I tried ur way but the terminal tells me that the package could not be found.

Comment: Hmm what ubuntu do you have?

Comment: Well, you may run `apt-cache policy` to check what apt repositories are in use. Make sure that `universe` repository is on (the third field in the output, smth like `saucy/universe` or `raring/universe`. Then try to perform `apt-cache search libntl-dev`.

Comment: I tried the `search` and nothing came up. And yes the `universe` repo is on the third output.

Comment: I think its solved. Now when i compile again, it gives me another error: `undefined reference to NTL..`

Comment: If "reference" is on stage then you've got to the linker. Try to specify a full path to libntl.a in the compilation command line.

Comment: Nevertheless, what is your Ubuntu version? What word do see before `universe` in the `apt-cache policy` output?

Comment: 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe Packages
     release v=10.04,o=Ubuntu,a=lucid,n=lucid,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: <offtopic>Uff, pretty vintage. Have you considered a system upgrade? Likely 10.04 Desktop is unsupported now and even security fixes aren't released anymore. Anyway NTL library does exist even in such an "ancient" Ubuntu http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libntl-dev .</offtopic>

Comment: Have you managed to link your program with explicit specification of libntl.a, smth like `g++ -o keygen keygen.cpp /path/to/libntl.a -lm`?

Comment: Erm no.. I'm doing this now : `g++ keygen.cpp -I include -L lib -lntl -lm`

Comment: When you simply specify -l<smth> then the linker searches "system-default" libraries paths such as /lib and /usr/lib and those you specified via -L linker flag. Therefore if your libntl.so isn't in those paths, the linker fails. Moreover if you use a dynamically loaded library (libntl.so or libntl.so.<some-numbers>) then upon application startup your library should be located somewhere in paths well known to Linux DLL loader (ld.so), see `man ld.so`.

Comment: If you don't wish to bother yourself with these gory details (I do understand you :) ) you may prefer to link a static version of NTL library, called libntl.a. Just locate where it resides and put the full path to it into the compilation/linkage command, as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Okay I did something like this `g++ keygen -I include -L /<fullpath>/lib/libntl.a -Intl -lm`. It still gives me the same error. Could something be wrong with the compilation line?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46521/discussion-between-user3159253-and-joel-seah)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The problem with your attempt to compile and output an executable file appears to be compiler's inability to link the necessary library after obtaining an object `.o` file.</strike>

Many people often test the point of fault by separating the two stages by first compiling `g++ -c` then by linking the libraries for an executable `g++ -o`. Although `-Wall` switch does not always work, trying it to provide you with as much information as possible during compilation can also be helpful.

Check [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/problem-with-g-linker-cannot-find-library-734085/) webpage. As for using different switches to link libraries try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g) webpage.

I'm not certain if it was a typo; but I wonder if the space between the switch and directory:
`-I ../include` and `-L ../lib`
was the problem.

Comment: Well, he hasn't reached the link stage. `KeyGen.cpp:9:20: error: NTL/ZZ.h: No such file or directory` is the message from compiler, more precisely, from preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

You said in comments:

> Icreated a folder called 'include' within the .cpp folder and included the NTL library in that folder already

But your compilation command says:

```
g++ keygen.cpp -o keygen -I ../include -L ../lib -lntl -lm.
```

It seems to me, you meant:

```
g++ keygen.cpp -o keygen -I ./include -L ../lib -lntl -lm.
#                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

since `..` goes up one directory.