# Linking with libconfig in c++ on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, linker, libconfig

I have a config file that contains:

```
#include "libconfig.h++"
```

I have installed libconfig via homebrew and I am trying to compile my c++ program so that I can use the library but I am having trouble linking to it.

The location of the libconfig .a files is located at /usr/local/Cellar/libconfig/1.4.9/lib/

The documentation says: `To link with the library, specify ‘-lconfig++’ as an argument to the linker.`

So I have been trying variations on `g++ config.cpp -L /usr/local/Cellar/libconfig/1.4.9/lib -lconfig++ -o out.o`

But I getting the same error message:

```
config.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'libconfig.h++' file not found
#include "libconfig.h++"
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about linker. The compiler says that it can't find the file you include in your cpp. If you have installed libconfig correctly, changing `#include "libconfig.h++"` to `#include <libconfig.h++>` will solve the problem. If it does not help, it would mean that there is no "libconfig.h++" in your [include path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g).