# how to install lp_solve library and use it in a C++ program

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I want to write the following include in my .cpp file :

```
#include <lpsolve/lp_lib.h>
```

But I really don't know how to install the library ...
The official project sourceforge page gives a .tar.gz with the following files :

```
liblpsolve55.a   lp_Hash.h  lp_matrix.h  lp_SOS.h  lp_utils.h   liblpsolve55.so  lp_lib.h   lp_mipbb.h   lp_types.h
```

I tried to put the .so file in /usr/lib but I don't know how to link it with the lp_lib.h file ... I don't understand anything about external librairies in C++... Please help

Comment: Your makefile (or whatever you are using) needs to know about the location of the lpsolve/lp_lib.h file i.e. where you have put lpsolve - are you using a makefile? CMake?...

Comment: Actually I have a lpsolve dir in /home/myname/Documents with all the listed above files. And it's just a single .cpp file so I compile with g++ ... No makefile

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g You need to use -I and -L as well