# Header files not found in c++, possible path issue

Tags: c++

I have a file structure like this:

```
main.cpp         --> #include <headers/f1/v.h>
headers/f1/v.h   --> #include <headers/f1/i.h>
headers/f1/i.h
```

`headers` is a directory of external library.
Compiled with 'g++ main.cpp' and got file not found error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:11:
./headers/f1/v.h:32:10: fatal error: 'headers/f1/i.h' file not found
#include <headers/f1/i.h>
```

Very new to c++. Really can't figure it out. What has been wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Use quotes for your own header files, not angle brackets: `#include "headers/f1/v.h"`.

Comment: " have a file structure like this:" I really doubt you do, as if you did all your source code would be in the root directory, which you almost certainly don't have write access to.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I think that the OP is starting from the project's directory, not the literal root directory.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks! Actually the entire /f1 folder comes from a library, that's why <> is used here. Also the main problem is that somehow v.h cannot find i.h and I don't suppose I should modified the library files. Any idea?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g

Comment: @user2683470: You should really stop calling it `/f1`, `/headers` etc like that. A leading slash is understood to mean "the root of the filesystem" and rules out a relative path. You probably meant `f1`, `headers` etc. (Notice that the compiler did it this way too, in its error message.) That way you don't confuse people! Cheers!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry about that!

Comment: @user2683470: No apology necessary!

Answer (score 1):

When including your own headers, in the same build tree, you should use quotes not angle brackets:

```
#include "headers/f1/v.h"
```

If you do get into the situation that you need `<>` for local files, for whatever reason, you could add the directory to your compiler's include path:

```
g++ main.cpp -I .
```

where `.` is the POSIX convention for "this directory".

---

Further reading:

- [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/560648)