# ld: library not found for -lcrypto

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am trying to run the http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup tutorial but stuck on this step:

```
 ./make.sh 
+ xcrun -sdk macosx g++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -Ilibplist/include -Ilibplist/libcnary/include -c -std=c++11 -o out/ldid.o ldid.cpp
+ xcrun -sdk macosx g++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -Ilibplist/include -Ilibplist/libcnary/include -o out/ldid out/ldid.o out/iterator.o out/list.o out/node.o out/node_iterator.o out/node_list.o out/base64.o out/bplist.o out/bytearray.o out/hashtable.o out/plist.o out/ptrarray.o out/xplist.o -x c lookup2.c -lxml2 -framework Security -lcrypto
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lcrypto
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if `-lcrypto` is installed on your system (on a Linux system, you could try calling `ldconfig -p | grep libcrypto`, but if you are using macOS, try to find some equivalent)
2. Make sure your g++ call contains proper path if this library is at some specific location that will not be searched by g++ by default.

You can read about including libraries and header files in this stack overflow topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6141166/4802475