# Preprocessor error: cblas.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, preprocessor

I am trying to see the output of a preprocessed .cpp file using the g++ compiler. I am doing this in the Windows command prompt. I type in `g++ -E file.cpp` in the command line but I get the error: `cblas.h: No such file or directory`

How do I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: ***How do I go about fixing this problem?*** Make sure that you add the include path of the folder containing the listed file to your compiler's command line. `g++ -I folder ...` related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install lapack from [here](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/)

Comment: Quite likely part of a correct answer, but too little is known about the problem as yet to be certain that this step has not been performed and there are other steps also required. For example, the command line given in the question is missing the options to direct the compiler to the location of the library's header files (and the options necessary to link the library in).