# Haskell compile DLL without copy-past ghc/include folder

Tags: windows, haskell, dll, ghc

I successfully created a DLL in Haskell. My problem is that everytime I want to compile a test program which loads and uses a function of my DLL I need to copy/paste files from C:\tools\ghc-9.0.1\include in my working directory.

The following files are:

```
HsFFI.h
ghcconfig.h
ghcautoconf.h
ghcplatform.h
stg/Types.h
```

I followed the tutorial on their documentation [https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html) but used other compiler commands to make it work.

This is my `Adder.hs` file

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Adder where

adder :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
adder x y = return (x+y)

foreign export ccall adder :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
```

This is my `StartEnd.c` file to start Haskell runtime

```
#include <Rts.h>

void HsStart()
{
   int argc = 1;
   char* argv[] = {"ghcDll", NULL}; // argv must end with NULL

   // Initialize Haskell runtime
   char** args = argv;
   hs_init(&argc, &args);
}

void HsEnd()
{
   hs_exit();
}
```

This is my `MyDef.def` file to add my functions

```
EXPORTS
  adder
  HsStart
  HsEnd
```

I compiled `Adder.hs` by writing `ghc -shared Adder.hs StartEnd.c -o Adder.dll Mydef.def`

This is my `test.cpp` file on c++. I wrote `#include "HsFFI.h"` to copy/paste `HsFFI.h` into my working directory as it couldn't find this file by itself when writing `#include <HsFFI.h>`. I compiled `test.cpp` by writing `g++ -o test test.cpp Adder.dll.a` My guess is that i need to make an environment variable so g++ can find this file, but how should i name this variable so g++ can find this file?

```
#include "HsFFI.h"
#include "Adder_stub.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    void HsStart();
    void HsEnd();
}

int main()
{
    HsStart();
    // can now safely call functions from the DLL
    printf("12 + 5 = %i\n", adder(12,5))    ;
    HsEnd();
    return 0;
}
```

I used ghc-9.0.1 and windows10.

Comment: Did you try passing the `-I C:\tools\ghc-9.0.1\include` option to g++? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g